# Sort table and select specific columns- mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to sort table by name:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ORDER BY 'name' DESC
```

This works however I want to only select columns 1 and 2 to show called 'username' and 'name. How would I do this.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear to me. Database tables don't have an order.  You can *query* the table and enforce an order on your *query*; is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is what you want:

```
select `username`, `name`
from `test`
order by logintime desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USERNAME,NAME
FROM `test`
ORDER BY `logintime` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must select information from the table and sort it when selecting. Based on the column(s) used when sorting, you need to create indexes. In your case create an index on `name`. Then, use a `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT `username`, `name`
FROM `test` 
ORDER BY `name` DESC
```

To create the index, run :

```
CREATE INDEX `name_index` 
ON `test` (`name`);
```

I recommend reading a bit about indexes : [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) and also the `EXPLAIN` statement : [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)